# Transmission Lines and Antennas

Tags: electromagnetism, antennas

In Transmission Lines, does the electric field exist between the two conducting wires or does it exist inside a wire, pushing the flow of electrons?

And do all antennas radiate energy by spark?

Answer (score 1):

Wires are conductors, which means (ideally) there are no electric fields formed inside of it. Instead, the charges hang around close to the surface because of something called [skin depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect). So to answer the first question, the field is between the wires, if you go to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line) page for transmission lines there is a nice GIF showing the electric field in between the wires.

As for the second question, I am unclear on what you mean by "*spark*". Antennas radiate energy by exciting a radiating element with a voltage gradient, which forms a time-changing EM field.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal TEM transmission line, the electric field is *normal* to the conductors and does not penetrate them; the ideal case is that of perfect conductors so there does not need to be any electric field to push the charges within. In practice, there is some penetration measured by the depth at which the field dwindles to $1/e$ of its surface value called the skin depth, and thus there is some ohmic loss.

There is a lovely analysis of the power flows around conductors in the second volume of the *Feynman Lectures*; [see especially Section 27.5](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_27.html)

All EM radiation, including that from antennas, comes from accelerated charges; the prototypical situation that demonstrates the mechanism is the derivation of the [Larmor Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula) for the power radiated by a uniformly accelerated charge and its relativistic generalization in the [Liénard–Wiechert potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential)